# How to convert a list of list to array in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this:

```
matriz:
[(79.754599999999996, 100.0),
(95.754599999999996, 100.0),
(79.754599999999996, 0),
(100.0, 100.0)]
```

Matriz is a list of list, and I want to convert it to an array. Currently i use this to get what i want:

```
matriz3 = np.array([matriz[0],matriz[1],matriz[2],matriz[3]])
matriz3

array([[  79.7546,  100.    ],
       [  95.7546,  100.    ],
       [  79.7546,    0.    ],
       [ 100.    ,  100.    ]])
```

How can i do this automaticly and more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `array`:

```
matriz3 = np.array(matriz)
```

Comment: Thanks! It solved my problem! :D